# PostgreSQL window function: partition by comparison

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, postgresql-performance

I'm trying to find the way of doing a comparison with the current row in the PARTITION BY clause in a WINDOW function in PostgreSQL query.

Imagine I have the short list in the following query of this 5 elements (in the real case, I have thousands or even millions of rows). I am trying to get for each row, the id of the next different element (event column), and the id of the previous different element.

```
WITH events AS(
  SELECT 1 as id, 12 as event, '2014-03-19 08:00:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 2 as id, 12 as event, '2014-03-19 08:30:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 3 as id, 13 as event, '2014-03-19 09:00:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 4 as id, 13 as event, '2014-03-19 09:30:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 5 as id, 12 as event, '2014-03-19 10:00:00'::timestamp as date
)
SELECT lag(id)  over w as previous_different, event
     , lead(id) over w as next_different
FROM events ev
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY event!=ev.event ORDER BY date ASC);
```

I know the comparison `event!=ev.event` is incorrect but that's the point I want to reach.

The result I get is (the same as if I delete the PARTITION BY clause):

```
 |12|2
1|12|3
2|13|4
3|13|5
4|12|
```

And the result I would like to get is:

```
 |12|3
 |12|3
2|13|5
2|13|5
4|12|
```

Anyone knows if it is possible and how? Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** I know I can do it with two `JOIN`s, a `ORDER BY` and a `DISTINCT ON`, but in the real case of millions of rows it is very inefficient:

```
WITH events AS(
  SELECT 1 as id, 12 as event, '2014-03-19 08:00:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 2 as id, 12 as event, '2014-03-19 08:30:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 3 as id, 13 as event, '2014-03-19 09:00:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 4 as id, 13 as event, '2014-03-19 09:30:00'::timestamp as date
  UNION SELECT 5 as id, 12 as event, '2014-03-19 10:00:00'::timestamp as date
)
SELECT DISTINCT ON (e.id, e.date) e1.id, e.event, e2.id
FROM events e
LEFT JOIN events e1 ON (e1.date<=e.date AND e1.id!=e.id AND e1.event!=e.event) 
LEFT JOIN events e2 ON (e2.date>=e.date AND e2.id!=e.id AND e2.event!=e.event) 
ORDER BY e.date ASC, e.id ASC, e1.date DESC, e1.id DESC, e2.date ASC, e2.id ASC
```

Comment: Unrelated: instead of writing a `SELECT ... UNION` to generate test data, you can use the much shorter `values` clause: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1471

Comment: Is the timestamp (which shouldn't be named `date`) unique?

Comment: That's a tricky one. You want a dynamic window that extends until some other value is different to the current value. I think this can only be done with the `RANGE` window clause, which PostgreSQL does not yet support. I'm afraid you might be stuck with the joins, since the before- and after- ranges are potentially unbounded.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I think I managed to get it un-stuck. :)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, NO, the timestamp could be repeated (two different events at the same second, then the order it gets to the id field). Sorry that it's called date (it was a translation from the original spanish names)..

Comment: @A It should be easy to adapt the query to your new specification. Add the `id` to `ORDER BY` et al. Remember to provide all the necessary information next time so we don't waste time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using several different [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) and two subqueries, this should work decently fast:

```
WITH events(id, event, ts) AS (
  VALUES
   (1, 12, '2014-03-19 08:00:00'::timestamp)
  ,(2, 12, '2014-03-19 08:30:00')
  ,(3, 13, '2014-03-19 09:00:00')
  ,(4, 13, '2014-03-19 09:30:00')
  ,(5, 12, '2014-03-19 10:00:00')
   )
SELECT first_value(pre_id)  OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ts)      AS pre_id
     , id, ts
     , first_value(post_id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ts DESC) AS post_id
FROM  (
   SELECT *, count(step) OVER w AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT id, ts
           , NULLIF(lag(event) OVER w, event) AS step
           , lag(id)  OVER w AS pre_id
           , lead(id) OVER w AS post_id
      FROM   events
      WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
      ) sub1
   WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY ts)
   ) sub2
ORDER  BY ts;
```

Using `ts` as name for the timestamp column.
Assuming `ts` to be unique - and ***indexed*** (a [unique constraint](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS) does that automatically).

In a test with a real life table with 50k rows it only needed *a single index scan*. So, should be decently fast even with big tables. In comparison, your query with join / distinct did not finish after a minute (as expected).
Even an optimized version, dealing with one cross join at a time (the left join with hardly a limiting condition is effectively a limited cross join) did not finish after a minute.

For best performance with a big table, tune your memory settings, in particular for [**`work_mem`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#GUC-WORK-MEM) (for big sort operations). Consider setting it (much) higher for your session temporarily if you can spare the RAM. Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106181/work-mem-in-postgresql-on-linux/8108807#8108807) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106181/work-mem-in-postgresql-on-linux/8108807#8108807).

#### How?

1. In subquery `sub1` look at the event from the previous row and only keep that if it has changed, thus marking the first element of a new group. At the same time, get the `id` of the previous and the next row (`pre_id`, `post_id`).
2. In subquery `sub2`, `count()` only counts non-null values. The resulting `grp` marks peers in blocks of consecutive same events.
3. In the final `SELECT`, take the first `pre_id` and the last `post_id` per group for each row to arrive at the desired result.
   Actually, this should be even faster in the outer `SELECT`:

   ```
    last_value(post_id) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY ts
                              RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                    AND     UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS post_id
   ```

   ... since the sort order of the window agrees with the window for `pre_id`, so only a single sort is needed. A quick test seems to confirm it. [More about this frame definition.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/9798/postgresql-view-with-max-min-with-id/9800#9800)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/1473)