# Querying count on daily basis with date constraints over multiple weeks

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, aggregate-functions, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to find the # active users over time on a daily basis.

A user is active when he has made **more than** 10 requests per week for 4 **consecutive weeks**.

ie. On Oct 31, 2014, a user is active if he has made more than 10 requests in total per week between:

1. Oct 24-Oct 30, 2014 **AND**
2. Oct 17-Oct 23, 2014 **AND**
3. Oct 10-Oct 16, 2014 **AND**
4. Oct 3-Oct 9, 2014

I have a table of `requests`:

```
CREATE TABLE requests (
  id text PRIMARY KEY, -- id of the request
  amount bigint,       -- sum of requests made by accounts_id to recipient_id,
                       -- aggregated on a daily basis based on "date"
  accounts_id text,    -- id of the user
  recipient_id text,   -- id of the recipient
  date timestamp       -- date that the request was made in YYYY-MM-DD
);
```

Sample values:

```
INSERT INTO requests2
VALUES
    ('1',  19, 'a1', 'b1', '2014-10-05 00:00:00'),
    ('2',  19, 'a2', 'b2', '2014-10-06 00:00:00'),
    ('3',  85, 'a3', 'b3', '2014-10-07 00:00:00'),
    ('4',  11, 'a1', 'b4', '2014-10-13 00:00:00'),
    ('5',  2,  'a2', 'b5', '2014-10-14 00:00:00'),
    ('6',  50, 'a3', 'b5', '2014-10-15 00:00:00'),
    ('7',  787323, 'a1', 'b6', '2014-10-17 00:00:00'),
    ('8',  33, 'a2', 'b8', '2014-10-18 00:00:00'),
    ('9',  14, 'a3', 'b9', '2014-10-19 00:00:00'),
    ('10', 11, 'a4', 'b10', '2014-10-19 00:00:00'),
    ('11', 1628, 'a1', 'b11', '2014-10-25 00:00:00'),
    ('13', 101, 'a2', 'b11', '2014-10-25 00:00:00');
```

Example output:

```
Date       | # Active users
-----------+---------------
10-01-2014 | 600
10-02-2014 | 703
10-03-2014 | 891
```

Here's what I tried to do to find the number of active users for a certain date (e.g. 10-01-2014):

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT accounts_id
   FROM requests
   WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2014-10-01'::date - interval '2 weeks' AND '2014-10-01'::date - interval '1 week'
   GROUP BY accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_1
JOIN
  (SELECT accounts_id
   FROM requests
   WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2014-10-01'::date - interval '3 weeks' AND '2014-10-01'::date - interval '2 week'
   GROUP BY accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_2 ON week_1.accounts_id = week_2.accounts_id
JOIN
  (SELECT accounts_id
   FROM requests
   WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2014-10-01'::date - interval '4 weeks' AND '2014-10-01'::date - interval '3 week'
   GROUP BY accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_3 ON week_2.accounts_id = week_3.accounts_id
JOIN
  (SELECT accounts_id
   FROM requests
   WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2014-10-01'::date - interval '5 weeks' AND '2014-10-01'::date - interval '4 week'
   GROUP BY accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_4 ON week_3.accounts_id = week_4.accounts_id
```

Since this is just the query to get the number for 1 day, I need to get this number on a daily basis over time. I think the idea is to do a join to get the date so I tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT week_1."Date_series",
       count(*)
FROM
  (SELECT to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Date_series",
          accounts_id
   FROM generate_series('2014-10-01'::date, CURRENT_DATE, '1 day') DAY, requests
   WHERE to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date BETWEEN requests.date::date - interval '2 weeks' AND requests.date::date - interval '1 week'
   GROUP BY "Date_series",
            accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_1
JOIN
  (SELECT to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Date_series",
          accounts_id
   FROM generate_series('2014-10-01'::date, CURRENT_DATE, '1 day') DAY, requests
   WHERE to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date BETWEEN requests.date::date - interval '3 weeks' AND requests.date::date - interval '2 week'
   GROUP BY "Date_series",
            accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_2 ON week_1.accounts_id = week_2.accounts_id
AND week_1."Date_series" = week_2."Date_series"
JOIN
  (SELECT to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Date_series",
          accounts_id
   FROM generate_series('2014-10-01'::date, CURRENT_DATE, '1 day') DAY, requests
   WHERE to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date BETWEEN requests.date::date - interval '4 weeks' AND requests.date::date - interval '3 week'
   GROUP BY "Date_series",
            accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_3 ON week_2.accounts_id = week_3.accounts_id
AND week_2."Date_series" = week_3."Date_series"
JOIN
  (SELECT to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS "Date_series",
          accounts_id
   FROM generate_series('2014-10-01'::date, CURRENT_DATE, '1 day') DAY, requests
   WHERE to_char(DAY::date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')::date BETWEEN requests.date::date - interval '5 weeks' AND requests.date::date - interval '4 week'
   GROUP BY "Date_series",
            accounts_id HAVING sum(amount) > 10) week_4 ON week_3.accounts_id = week_4.accounts_id
AND week_3."Date_series" = week_4."Date_series"
GROUP BY week_1."Date_series"
```

However, I think I'm not getting the right answer and I'm not sure why. Any tips/ guidance/ pointers is much appreciated! :) :)

PS. I'm using Postgres 9.3

Comment: Please provide the table definition as `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d tbl` in psql. Some sample values would also go a long way.

Comment: Hi @ErwinBrandstetter i've added the table definition and sample values as requested. :) thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a long answer how to make your queries short. :)

#### Table

Building on my table (before you provided table definition with different (*odd!*) data types:

```
CREATE TABLE requests (
   id           int
 , accounts_id  int  -- (id of the user)
 , recipient_id int  -- (id of the recipient)
 , date         date -- (date that the request was made in YYYY-MM-DD)
 , amount       int  -- (# of requests by accounts_id for the day)
);
```

### Active Users for given day

The list of "active users" for **one given day**:

```
SELECT accounts_id
FROM  (
   SELECT w.w, r.accounts_id
   FROM  (
      SELECT w
           , day - 6 - 7 * w AS w_start
           , day     - 7 * w AS w_end   
      FROM  (SELECT '2014-10-31'::date - 1 AS day) d  -- effective date here
           , generate_series(0,3) w
      ) w
   JOIN   requests r ON r."date" BETWEEN w_start AND w_end
   GROUP  BY w.w, r.accounts_id
   HAVING sum(r.amount) > 10
   ) sub
GROUP  BY 1
HAVING count(*) = 4;
```

#### Step 1

In the innermost **subquery `w`** (for "week") build the bounds of the 4 weeks of interest from a `CROSS JOIN` of the given day - 1 with the output of `generate_series(0-3)`.

To add / subtract days to / from a `date` (not from a timestamp!) just add / subtract `integer` numbers. The expression `day - 7 * w` subtracts 0-3 times 7 days from the given date, arriving at the *end* dates for each week (`w_end`).
Subrtract another 6 days (not 7!) from each to compute the respective *start* (`w_start`).
Additionally, keep the week number `w` (0-3) for the later aggregation.

#### Step 2

In **subquery `sub`** join rows from `requests` to the set of 4 weeks, where the date lies between start and end date. `GROUP BY` the week number `w` and the `accounts_id`.
Only weeks with more than 10 requests total qualify.

#### Step 3

In the **outer `SELECT`** count the number of weeks each user (`accounts_id`) qualified. Must be 4 to qualify as "active user"

### Count of active users per day

This is ***dynamite***.
Wrapped in in a simple SQL function to simplify general use, but the query can be used on its own just as well:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_active_users (_now date = now()::date, _days int = 3)
  RETURNS TABLE (day date, users int) AS
$func$
WITH r AS (
   SELECT accounts_id, date, sum(amount)::int AS amount
   FROM   requests
   WHERE  date BETWEEN _now - (27 + _days) AND _now - 1
   GROUP  BY accounts_id, date
   )
SELECT date + 1, count(w_ct = 4 OR NULL)::int
FROM  (
   SELECT accounts_id, date
        , count(w_amount > 10 OR NULL)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY accounts_id, dow ORDER BY date DESC
                         ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 3 FOLLOWING) AS w_ct
   FROM  (
      SELECT accounts_id, date, dow   
           , sum(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY accounts_id ORDER BY date DESC
                         ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 6 FOLLOWING) AS w_amount
      FROM  (SELECT _now - i AS date, i%7 AS dow
             FROM   generate_series(1, 27 + _days) i) d -- period of interest
      CROSS  JOIN (
             SELECT accounts_id FROM r
             GROUP  BY 1
             HAVING count(*) > 3 AND sum(amount) > 39  -- enough rows & requests
             AND    max(date) > min(date) + 15) a      -- can cover 4 weeks
      LEFT   JOIN r USING (accounts_id, date)
      ) sub1
   WHERE date > _now - (22 + _days)  -- cut off 6 trailing days now - useful?
   ) sub2
GROUP  BY date
ORDER  BY date DESC
LIMIT  _days
$func$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

The function takes any day (`_now`), "today" by default, and the number of days (`_days`) in the result, 3 by default. Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_active_users('2014-10-31', 5);
```

Or without parameters to use defaults:

```
SELECT * FROM f_active_users();
```

The approach is **different from the first query**.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fe55f/1) with both queries and variants for your table definition.

#### Step 0

In the CTE `r` pre-aggregate amounts per `(accounts_id, date)` for only the period of interest, for better performance. The table is only scanned *once*, the suggested index (see blow) will kick in here.

#### Step 1

In the inner subquery `d` generate the necessary list of days: `27 + _days` rows, where `_days` is the desired number of rows in the output, effectively 28 days or more.
While being at it, compute the day of the week (`dow`) to be used for aggregating in step 3. `i%7` coincides with weekly intervals, the query works for *any* interval, though.

In the inner subquery `a` generate a unique list of users (`accounts_id`) that exist in CTE `r` and pass some first superficial tests (sufficient rows spanning sufficient time with sufficient total requests).

#### Step 2

Generate a Cartesian product from `d` and `a` with a `CROSS JOIN` to have **one row for every relevant day for every relevant user**. `LEFT JOIN` to `r` to append the amount of requests (if any). No `WHERE` condition, we want every day in the result, even if there are no active users at all.

Compute the total amount for the past week (`w_amount`) in the same step using a [Window functions with a **custom frame**.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html) Example:

- [How to use a ring data structure in window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030179/how-to-use-a-ring-data-structure-in-window-functions/25039137#25039137)

#### Step 3

Cut off the last 6 days now; which is *optional* and may or may not help performance. Test it: `WHERE date >= _now - (21 + _days)`

Count the weeks where the minimum amount is met (`w_ct`) in a similar window function, this time partitioned by `dow` additionally to only have same weekdays for the past 4 weeks in the frame (which carry the sum of the respective past week).
The expression `count(w_amount > 10 OR NULL)` only counts rows with more than 10 requests. Detailed explanation:

- [Compute percents from SUM() in the same SELECT sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15644713/compute-percents-from-sum-in-the-same-select-sql-query/15650897#15650897)

#### Step 4

In the outer `SELECT` group by `date` and count users that passed all 4 weeks (`count(w_ct = 4 OR NULL)`). Add 1 to the date to compensate off-by-1, `ORDER` and `LIMIT` to the requested number of days.

### Performance and outlook

The perfect index for both queries would be:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON requests (date, accounts_id, amount);
```

Performance should be good, but get even (much) better with the upcoming Postgres **9.4**, due to the new **moving aggregate** support:

[**Moving-aggregate support** in the Postgres Wiki.](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.4#Moving-aggregate_support)
[Moving aggregates in the 9.4 manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/xaggr.html#XAGGR-MOVING-AGGREGATES)

Aside: don't call a `timestamp` column "date", it's a `timestamp`, not a `date`. Better yet, never use basic type names like `date` or `timestamp` as identifier. Ever.

Comment: could you explain this please? im lost in the sub query, especially the part on "day - 6 - 7 * w AS w_start" and " day     - 7 * w as w_end"

Comment: @christinang89: Added a solution for the main problem and an epic explanation.

Comment: thanks for your very epic explanation @ErwinBrandstetter !! Answers like this make me love the SO community so so much :)

Comment: @christinang89: Added some more optimizations. In particular, rule out "impossible" users early on, to reduce number of rows processed. Updated fiddle, too.