# Recursive subtraction of deposit from balance rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Consider the following 2 tables:

TABLE A:

```
PIN | ENCOUNTER | BALANCE | REFERENCE_DATE 
------------------------------------------
P1  | ABC       | 100     | 11-19-2014     
P1  | HJI       | 300     | 11-20-2014     
P1  | PIY       | 700     | 11-21-2014     
P2  | CDO       | 200     | 11-20-2014     
P2  | NHG       | 200     | 11-21-2014    
P3  | CVB       | 500     | 11-20-2014
P3  | SJK       | 100     | 11-21-2014
```

TABLE B:

```
PIN | DEPOSIT
-------------
P1  | 1000
P2  | 400
P3  | 100
```

Initially Table `B`'s `DEPOSIT` value is to be subtracted from the `BALANCE` in table `A` with the earliest `REFERENCE_DATE` matched by the `PIN`. Should the difference be greater than 0, it would be subtracted from the `BALANCE` in the next row until the remaining `DEPOSIT` becomes less than or equal to 0.

The result after subtracting the deposit from the balances would look like this. I've included another column wherein the deposits are divided per encounter:

```
PIN | ENCOUNTER | BALANCE | REFERENCE_DATE | DEPOSITS_BREAKDOWN
---------------------------------------------------------------
P1  | ABC       | 0       | 11-19-2014     | 100
P1  | HJI       | 0       | 11-20-2014     | 300
P1  | PIY       | 100     | 11-21-2014     | 600
P2  | CDO       | 0       | 11-20-2014     | 200
P2  | NHG       | 0       | 11-21-2014     | 200
P3  | CVB       | 400     | 11-20-2014     | 100
P3  | SJK       | 100     | 11-21-2014     | 0
```

My Postgres version is 9.3. I'm struggling to formulate the query for this one.

Comment: The last result row should probably be 500, not 100.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, if so, then I have wasted 30 minutes. This `100` is a bit tough to deal with.

Comment: Actually the last row is really 100. the 100 deposit allocated for P3 rows in table A is already subtracted to the row with CVB encounter.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. But is it possible to also list in another column how much the deposits were divided? I've updated the result table.

Comment: Yes, that's cheaply possible. Aside: are you aware that without @-reply nobody was notified of your comment? Found it by chance.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter I wasn't aware of using @-reply until now. Thanks! I'm beginning to learn window functions because of you answer. Last question regarding the clause, ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING. Is it like referring to the rows before the current row?

Comment: Yes. I added another link to an answer with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Set to 0 as far as `DEPOSIT` covers `BALANCE`

As you clarified, you don't want a running sum of `BALANCE`, just set to 0 until `DEPOSIT` is spent:

```
SELECT PIN, ENCOUNTER
     , CASE WHEN last_sum >= DEPOSIT THEN BALANCE
            ELSE GREATEST (last_sum + BALANCE - DEPOSIT, 0) END AS BALANCE
     , REFERENCE_DATE
     , CASE WHEN last_sum >= DEPOSIT THEN 0
            ELSE LEAST (BALANCE, DEPOSIT - last_sum) END AS DEPOSITS_BREAKDOWN
FROM (
   SELECT a.*
        , COALESCE(sum(a.BALANCE) OVER (
                         PARTITION BY PIN ORDER BY a.REFERENCE_DATE
                         ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                                          AND 1 PRECEDING), 0) AS last_sum
        , COALESCE(b.DEPOSIT, 0) AS DEPOSIT
   FROM        table_a a
   LEFT   JOIN table_b b USING (pin)
   ) sub;
```

Returns your desired result exactly.

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3080/28)

- I adopted the idea for the simpler join from @vyegorov as commented.
- `LEFT JOIN` to `table_b` - that leaves the possibility that no row in `table_b` might be found.
- In the subquery, compute the running sum of `BALANCE` up until the last row (`last_sum`). Use a custom frame in the window function for this. And `COALESCE` to default to 0 where there are not rows. Related answers with more explanation for the custom frame:

  - [How to use a ring data structure in window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030179/how-to-use-a-ring-data-structure-in-window-functions/25039137#25039137)
  - [Querying count on daily basis with date constraints over multiple weeks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26899491/querying-count-on-daily-basis-with-date-constraints-over-multiple-weeks/26899977#26899977)
- In the final `SELECT`, return  original `BALANCE` if `last_sum` is equal or greater than `DEPOSIT` (it has been spent). ELSE return the remaining difference or 0 is the running sum of `BALANCE` (`last_sum + BALANCE`) is smaller than `DEPOSIT`.

#### Running sum

Previous (simpler) answer with the `BALANCE` as running sum (last row 500 instead of 100):

```
SELECT a.PIN, a.ENCOUNTER
     , GREATEST(sum(a.BALANCE) OVER (PARTITION BY PIN ORDER BY a.REFERENCE_DATE) 
                 - COALESCE(b.DEPOSIT, 0), 0) AS BALANCE
     , a.REFERENCE_DATE
FROM   table_a      a
LEFT   JOIN table_b b USING (pin);
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this query:

```sql
SELECT *,
       sum(balance) OVER w                          balance_accum,
       greatest(deposit - sum(balance) OVER w, 0)   deposit_new,
       greatest(sum(balance) OVER w - deposit, 0)   balance_new
  FROM table_a JOIN table_b USING(pin)
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY pin ORDER BY reference_date)
 ORDER BY pin, reference_date;
```

<kbd>**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3080/14)**</kbd>

As Erwin mentioned, this one assumes last row contains `500` rather then `100`.

---

**EDIT**:

And this query produces the desired output:

```sql
SELECT s.*,
       CASE WHEN min(deposit_new) OVER w = 0 THEN 0 
            ELSE least(min(deposit_new) OVER w, deposit_diff) END     deposit_used,
       balance -
         CASE WHEN min(deposit_new) OVER w = 0 THEN 0
              ELSE least(min(deposit_new) OVER w, deposit_diff) END   balance_real
  FROM
  (
    SELECT *,
           sum(balance) OVER w                                      balance_accum,
           greatest(coalesce(deposit,0) - sum(balance) OVER w, 0)   deposit_new,
           least(balance, coalesce(deposit,0))                      deposit_diff
      FROM table_a LEFT JOIN table_b USING(pin)
    WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY pin ORDER BY reference_date)
  ) s
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY pin ORDER BY reference_date
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
 ORDER BY pin, reference_date;
```

What's on here (subquery):

- as Erwin suggests, `LEFT JOIN` and `coalesce(deposit,0)` are used to keep entries without deposits;
- running total of actual `balance` values is computed and substracted from `deposit` (column `deposit_new` in the output);
- `deposit_diff` is a least of `balance` and `deposit`, it is used to adjust balances in the outer part.

In the outer part:

- check minimal `deposit_new` value and if `0` is reached, then all further "usage" is skipped;
- otherwise take least of `deposit_new` and `deposit_diff` values;
- checks are done for all preceding rows in the group.

Subquery is required for I have to use results of the window functions in the logic.

<kbd>**[SQL Fiddle 2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d3080/21)**</kbd>

Comment: It's a good idea to join to every row in table_a. One subquery with window function less.