# How to work with a iterator variable on a dynamic select query in PL/pgSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, iterator, plpgsql, window-functions

I need to deliver a cash flow report in PostgreSQL 9.1.

In the balance line (BalanceLine), a function (getBalanceLine) is responsible for fetching the sum of the bank accounts and its credit or debit position.

The number row (`num_row`) needs to be decreased until zero to indicate to the function `getBalanceLine` that a temporary table has to be `DROP`ed. That temporary table keeps the balance line results as "working memory" for the calculations.

The problem is that the `num_row` variable, on the function `getBalanceLine` is not decreasing according with instructions on my `LOOP` clause.

The following is the PL/pgSQL function:

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS report_cash_flow();

CREATE FUNCTION report_cash_flow() RETURNS TABLE(Date date, Company varchar(128), Bank varchar(64), Partner varchar(128), Document varchar(64), Credit numeric, Debit numeric, Line integer, BalanceLine numeric) AS 
$BODY$

DECLARE
    num_row int := 0;

BEGIN

    num_row = ( SELECT
                COUNT(*)
            FROM
                account_move_line aml
                INNER JOIN  res_company rc ON rc.id = aml.company_id
                INNER JOIN  res_partner rp ON rp.id = aml.partner_id
                INNER JOIN  account_journal aj ON aj.id = aml.journal_id
                INNER JOIN  account_account aa ON aa.id = aml.account_id
            WHERE
                aml.state = 'valid'
                AND aml.reconcile_id IS NULL );


    FOR Date, Company, Bank, Partner, Document, Credit, Debit, Line, BalanceLine IN

        SELECT
            aml.date_maturity AS Date,
            rc.name AS Company,
            aj.name AS Bank,
            rp.name AS Partner,
            aml.name AS Document,
            aml.credit AS Credit,
            aml.debit AS Debit,
            num_row AS Line,
            getBalanceLine(aml.credit, aml.debit, num_row) AS BalanceLine
        FROM
            account_move_line aml
            INNER JOIN  res_company rc ON rc.id = aml.company_id
            INNER JOIN  res_partner rp ON rp.id = aml.partner_id
            INNER JOIN  account_journal aj ON aj.id = aml.journal_id
            INNER JOIN  account_account aa ON aa.id = aml.account_id
        WHERE
            aml.state = 'valid'
            AND aml.reconcile_id IS NULL
        ORDER BY
            Document

        LOOP
            num_row := num_row - 1;
            RAISE NOTICE '%', num_row;
            RETURN NEXT;

        END LOOP;

    RETURN;

END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

SELECT * FROM report_cash_flow();
```

The following is the result of the query:

```
date        company     bank    partner     document    credit  debit     line  balanceline
01/10/2013  Company 1   Bank 1  Partner 1   00003621/1  0.00    520.56    4       1.024,00
01/10/2013  Company 1   Bank 2  Partner 2   00003622/1  32.00   0.00      4         922,00
09/10/2014  Company 1   Bank 1  Partner 3   00003623/1  0.00    18009.65  4     -17.087,65
10/10/2014  Company 1   Bank 2  Partner 4   00003624/1  6126.95 0.00      4     -10.960,70
```

The following is the result of `RAISE NOTICE '%', num_row`:

```
NOTICE:  4
NOTICE:  3
NOTICE:  2
NOTICE:  1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query providing the rows for your `FOR` loop is executed ***once*** before the first iteration of the loop. You would have to call the function `getBalanceLine()` in the loop, not in the base query.

However, your whole approach is needlessly verbose and expensive.

#### Simplify, step 1

```
CREATE FUNCTION report_cash_flow()
  RETURNS TABLE(Date date, Company text, Bank text, Partner text, Document text, Credit numeric, Debit numeric, Line integer, BalanceLine numeric) AS 
$func$
DECLARE
    _iterator int := 0;
BEGIN
    FOR Date, Company, Bank, Partner, Document, Credit, Debit, Line IN
        SELECT  aml.date_maturity AS Date -- alias useless
                rc.name AS Company,
                aj.name AS Bank,
                rp.name AS Partner,
                aml.name AS Document,
                aml.credit AS Credit,
                aml.debit AS Debit,
                count(*) OVER () AS Line  -- = initial num_row
        FROM    account_move_line aml
        JOIN    res_company       rc ON rc.id = aml.company_id
        JOIN    res_partner       rp ON rp.id = aml.partner_id
        JOIN    account_journal   aj ON aj.id = aml.journal_id
        JOIN    account_account   aa ON aa.id = aml.account_id
        WHERE   aml.state = 'valid'
        AND     aml.reconcile_id IS NULL
        ORDER   BY Document
    LOOP
        BalanceLine := getBalanceLine(Credit, Debit, Line - _iterator);
        RETURN NEXT;
        _iterator := _iterator + 1;
        RAISE NOTICE '%', Line - _iterator;         
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- Execute function in loop.
- No need to run a second query for the count. You can do this in a single `SELECT` with a window function.
- Introduce an additional variable to count loops,  `_iterator` in my case.
  I prepend variables with `_` to avoid naming collisons.
- Don't quote the language name `plpgsql`, it's an identifier.

#### Simplify, step 2

You can probably use this single plain query with [**window functions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) instead:

```
SELECT aml.date_maturity AS Date
     , rc.name AS Company
     , aj.name AS Bank
     , rp.name AS Partner
     , aml.name AS Document
     , aml.credit
     , aml.debit
     , count(*) OVER () AS Line  -- or the decreasing number?
     , getBalanceLine(aml.credit
                    , aml.debit
                    , count(*) OVER () + 1 -
                      row_number() OVER (ORDER  BY Document)) AS BalanceLine 
FROM   account_move_line aml
JOIN   res_company       rc ON rc.id = aml.company_id
JOIN   res_partner       rp ON rp.id = aml.partner_id
JOIN   account_journal   aj ON aj.id = aml.journal_id
JOIN   account_account   aa ON aa.id = aml.account_id
WHERE  aml.state = 'valid'
AND    aml.reconcile_id IS NULL
ORDER  BY Document;
```

Or use the more sophisticated:

```
count(*) OVER (ORDER BY Document
               ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
```

More explanation:

- [How to use a ring data structure in window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030179/how-to-use-a-ring-data-structure-in-window-functions/25039137#25039137)

Comment: Erwin I realy apreciated your help. The trick was (on step 1) manipulate the BalanceLine on LOOP clause. Thank you for all explanation.