# Given time/interval to calculate open/high/low/close value in each grouped data

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

Suppose raw data is:

```
  Timestamp   High Low Volume
  10:24.22345 100   99  10
  10:24.23345 110   97  20
  10:24.33455 97    89  40
  10:25.33455 60    40  50
  10:25.93455 40    20  60
```

With a sample time of 1 second, the output data should be as following (they are grouped by second):

```
  Timestamp   Open Close High  Low Volume 
  10:24         82   83   110   89  70     
  10:25         50   40   60    20  110
```

- `Open` means the *price* of the earliest data in the group
- `Close` means the  price of the lastest data in the group
- `Volume` means the sum(Volume) in the group

The sampling unit from varying from `1 second, 5 sec, 1 minute, 1 hour, 1 day, ...`

Now I can get the High, Low, Volume  by the following SQL:

```
SELECT date_trunc(\'#{interval}\', ticktime) AS ticktime_stamp,
       max(bid_price) as high,
       min(bid_price) as low,
       sum(bid_volume) as volume,
       max(product_type) as product_type
FROM   czces
WHERE  ticktime >=  \'#{begin_time}\'::timestamp
AND  ticktime <  \'#{end_time}\'::timestamp
AND  product_type =\'#{product_type}\'
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY ticktime_stamp ASC
```

But how to get the `open`, `close` value in each group based on the above query?

Comment: Your raw data has no price and the numbers for `Open` and `Close` don't match. Can you make that consistent?

Comment: Can you add an SQLFiddle with the actual table and some data? I don't really see how you have `82` at Open since that's not within the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) combined with `DISTINCT ON` for that:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (1)
       date_trunc('#{interval}', ticktime) AS ticktime_stamp
     , max(bid_price)         OVER w AS high
     , min(bid_price)         OVER w AS low
     , sum(bid_volume)        OVER w AS volume
     , max(product_type)      OVER w AS product_type
     , min(product_type)      OVER w AS product_type
     , first_value(bid_price) OVER w AS open
     , last_value(bid_price)  OVER w AS close
FROM   czces
WHERE  ticktime >= '#{begin_time}'::timestamp
AND    ticktime <  '#{end_time}'::timestamp
AND    product_type ='#{product_type}'
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY date_trunc('#{interval}', ticktime) ORDER BY ticktime
             ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
                      AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
ORDER  BY 1;
```

Explanation for the custom window frame:

- [How to use a ring data structure in window functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25030179/how-to-use-a-ring-data-structure-in-window-functions/25039137#25039137)
- [PostgreSQL window function: partition by comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22512335/postgresql-window-function-partition-by-comparison/22521489#22521489)

Explanation for `DISTINCT ON`:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Answer (score 2):

The query you are looking for is most likely this, but without actual testing data it's hard to be certain.

```
SELECT
  min(date_trunc('second', "Timestamp")) OVER minutes "Timestamp",
  first_value("Price") OVER minutes "Open",
  last_value("Price") OVER minutes "Close",
  max("High") OVER minutes "High",
  min("Low") OVER minutes "Low",
  sum("Volume") OVER minutes "Volume"
FROM czces
WINDOW minutes AS (
    PARTITION BY date_trunc('second', "Timestamp")
    ORDER BY "Timestamp"
);
```