# Efficiently selecting distinct (a, b) from big table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group, database-indexes, postgresql-performance

I have a table with around 54 million rows in a Postgres 9.6 DB and would like to find all distinct pairs of two columns (there are around 4 million such values). I have an index over the two columns of interest:

```
create index ab_index on tbl (a, b)
```

What is the most efficient way to get such pairs? I have tried:

```
select a,b
from tbl
where a>$previouslargesta
group by a,b
order by a,b
limit 1000
```

And also:

```
select distinct(a,b)
from tbl
where a>previouslargesta
order by a,b
limit 1000
```

Also this recursive query:

```
with recursive t AS (
  select min(a) AS a from tbl
  union all
  select (select min(a) from tickets where a > t.a)
  FROM t)
select a FROM t
```

But all are slooooooow.

**Is there a faster way to get this information?**

Comment: Is `LIMIT 1000` for testing or do you only need 1000 result rows? Is it important which rows? (`ORDER BY a,b` is also important?) Show your exact index definition. Avg. row size in bytes? Can you show the recursive query you tried?

Comment: hi @erwinbrandstetter. Thanks for taking an interest in my problem. I ultimately need to get all the combinations of a and b. I was using page sizes of 1000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table has 54 million rows and ...

> there are around 4 million such values

7,4 % of all rows is a high percentage, an index can mostly only help by providing pre-sorted data, ideally in an [index-only scan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-index-only-scans.html). There are more sophisticated techniques for smaller result sets (see below), and there are *much* faster ways for paging which returns much fewer rows at a time (see below) but for the general case a plain `DISTINCT` may be among the fastest:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b  -- *no* parentheses
FROM   tbl;
-- ORDER  BY a, b      -- ORDER BY wasn't not mentioned as requirement ...
```

Don't confuse it with `DISTINCT ON`, which would require parentheses. See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7630564/939860)

The B-tree index `ab_index` you have on `(a, b)` is already the best index for this. It has to be scanned in its entirety, though. The challenge is to have enough **`work_mem`** to process all in **RAM**. With standard settings it occupies at least 1831 MB on disk, typically more with some bloat. If you can afford it, run the query with a `work_mem` setting of 2 GB (or more) in your session. See:

- [Configuration parameter work_mem in PostgreSQL on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8106181/configuration-parameter-work-mem-in-postgresql-on-linux/8108807#8108807)

```
SET work_mem = '2 GB';
SELECT DISTINCT a, b ...
RESET work_mem;
```

A read-only table helps. Else you need aggressive enough `VACUUM` settings to allow an **index-only scan**. And some more RAM, yet, would help (with appropriate settings) to keep the index cashed.

Also upgrade to the **latest version** of Postgres (11.3 as of writing). There have been many improvements for big data.

### Paging

If you want to add **paging** as indicated by your sample query, urgently consider **ROW value comparison**. See:

- [Optimize query with OFFSET on large table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110504/optimize-query-with-offset-on-large-table/34291099#34291099)
- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM   tbl
WHERE  (a, b) > ($previous_a, $previous_b)   -- !!!
ORDER  BY a, b
LIMIT  1000;
```

### Recursive CTE

This also may or may not be faster for the general big query as well. For the small subset, it becomes *much* more attractive:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   (  -- parentheses required du to LIMIT 1
   SELECT a, b
   FROM   tbl
   WHERE  (a, b) > ($previous_a, $previous_b)   -- !!!
   ORDER  BY a, b
   LIMIT  1
   )
   UNION ALL
   SELECT x.a, x.b
   FROM   cte c
   CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
      SELECT t.a, t.b
      FROM   tbl t
      WHERE  (t.a, t.b) > (c.a, c.b) -- lateral reference
      ORDER  BY t.a, t.b
      LIMIT  1
      ) x
   )
TABLE cte
LIMIT 1000;
```

This can make perfect use of your index and should be ***as fast as it gets***.

Further reading:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest row per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-row-per-user/25536748#25536748)

For repeated use and no or little write load on the table, consider a [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html), based on one of the above queries - for much faster read performance.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot guarantee for performance at Postgres, but this is a technique i had used on sql server in a similar case and proven faster than others:

get distinct A into a temp a

get distinct B into a temp b

cross a and b temps to Cartesian into a temp abALL

rank the abALL (optionally)

create a view myview as select top 1 a,b from tbl (your_main_table)

join temp abALL with myview into a temp abCLEAN

rank abCLEAN here if you havent rank above